# Writting custom functionality of google cloud messaging service

Tags: android, node.js, client-server, push

What I need is to create a android game app where user interact with each other.
And user can chat as well. 
I was in the initial R & D face, I was looking into the ways I can implement push to the android device.

What I found was over net is the following two poular ways:
1)  using nodejs.
2) using google cloud messaging.

But the problem is:

**nodejs**: nodejs is a javascript library it will NOT work for background processes.

**google cloud messaging** : I don't want to use it; because it is google dependent and I may want to connect blackberry, windows and android as well.

Any one with a better solution or Am wrong somewhere ??

Comment: What do you mean won't work for background processes? Node.js is run server-side.

Comment: node js client that I can add to a android app via phone gap or other web frame work .. m talking with respect to mobile app